# How to enable/disable elements from an array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to create a component where I have a bunch of boxes from an array, that can be turned 'on' and 'off' when each one is individually clicked.

Currently, only a single item from the array can be switched 'on' (shown by the item turning green), however, I would like to be able to turn each item on/off individually.

Interacting with one element should not affect any of the others.

How do I achieve this?

My click event:

```
  handleOnClick = (val, i) => {
    this.setState({active: i}, () => console.log(this.state.active, 'active'))
  }
```

Rendering the boxes:

```
 renderBoxes = () => {

    const options = this.state.needsOptions.map((val, i) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={i}
            style={{...style.box, background: i === this.state.active ? 'green' : ''}}
            onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(val, i)}
          >
            {val}
          </button>
        )
      })

      return options

  }
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/RdzxLR?editors=0011)

Comment: To store the state of a bunch of boxes you need an array of bools, like `[true, false, false]`. You currently have a single variable storing an index instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to create a `Box` component with its own active state, and pass this to the map in `renderBoxes`. The benefit of doing it this way is that each Box component will have its own state independent of the parent. That way you can have more than one component as active.

so...

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      active: false
    }
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
  }

  render(){
    const { key, children }= this.props
    return (
      <button
            key={key}
            style={{...style.box, background:     this.state.active ? 'green' : ''}}
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}
          >
            {children}
          </button>
    )
  }
}
```

then have renderBoxes be...

```
renderBoxes = () => {

    const options = this.state.needsOptions.map((val, i) => {
        return (
          <Box
            key={i}
          >
            {val}
          </Box>
        )
      })

      return options

  }
```

[here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/Rushadee/pen/VRJQZP?editors=1111) I forked off yours.